# mergExt - mergFTPD external - any callback message or result after successfully starting ftp daemon?

Tags: livecode

Is there a way to get information back from mergFTPD (mergExt component), if the ftp daemon was started successfully?

Or do i have to check if ftp deamon is running with standard LC commands in the iOS app?

For example

after starting the deamon put a file into the defined folder using a put url "file:...
and then trying to get that file back with a put URL "ftp://..... "

this works, but using a callback message or getting a result after starting the daemon would be
more comfortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no callback I can use here